# Sakila db SQL find total combined film length of Sci-Fi films for every actor

Tags: sql

For reference I am working on the Sakila rental DVD database outlined [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html) (#2):

Basically, I am trying to make a query to list every actor and their total run time of sci-fi films they've been in. They should be in the table with a total run time of NULL or 0 if they've never been in a sci-fi film.

I was able to figure out how to get a list of actors who HAVE been in sci-fi but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong to exclude any actors who haven't been in a sci-fi film.

```
SELECT act.first_name, act.last_name, SUM(fm.length)
FROM film fm
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.film_id = fm.film_id
INNER JOIN actor act ON fa.actor_id = act.actor_id
INNER JOIN film_category fc ON fm.film_id = fc.film_id
INNER JOIN category cat ON fc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.name = 'Sci-Fi'
GROUP BY act.first_name, act.last_name
ORDER BY act.last_name ASC
```

I have tried changing to LEFT JOINs for the two rows that get the actors (the first two joins) as I thought that might solve the issue of actors without the film not being included but I ended up with the same results.

Comment: can you create sql fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about a subquery that aggregates by category before you do the left loin:

```
SELECT 
  act.first_name, 
  act.last_name, 
  cat_aggregate.sum_length
FROM 
  actor act 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      cat.name,
      fa.actor_id,
      SUM(fm.length) sum_length
    FROM
      film fm
      INNER JOIN film_actor    fa ON fa.film_id = fm.film_id
      INNER JOIN film_category fc ON fc.film_id = fm.film_id
      INNER JOIN category     cat ON cat.category_id = fc.category_id
    GROUP BY
      cat.name,
      fa.actor_id
  ) cat_aggregate ON cat_aggregate.actor_id = act.actor_id
WHERE
  cat_aggregate.cat_name = 'Sci-Fi'
ORDER BY 
  act.last_name,
  act.first_name
```

Actors with no appearance in a Sci-Fi movie will show up with a sum_length of `NULL`.

If you want you can move the `WHERE cat_aggregate.cat_name = 'Sci-Fi'` into the sub-query as `WHERE cat.name = 'Sci-Fi'`.